# Honda CBR 250 won't start after heavy rains, puttering noise

Tags: motorcycle, starting, sparkplugs

There has been heavy rain and yesterday I couldn't start my bike. The main and other fuses are not blown. I ride it regularly.

Turning the bike on: https://vid.me/pYNw. The high-pitch noise is not typical.

Hitting and holding the ignition switch, pointing to where I think the sound is from: https://vid.me/lak6

Any idea what's making this noise and why the bike won't start? Spark plug?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the vids w/ audio.  Made it real easy to understand what you're experiencing.  Best of luck.

Comment: Spark plugs or fuel pump

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theory**

It sounds as if the starter solenoid is getting 'stuck' due to low voltage.  That is the second buzzing noise.  The high pitched sound is your fuel pump priming your system and is normal.

Perhaps the rain created a grounding situation that drained your battery a bit.  Regardless of that speculation, here is the fix.

Charge the battery.  I believe that is all you will have to do.

If you choose to jump start your bike off a car w/ jumper cables

## DO NOT START THE CAR

The additional amperage from the alternator can potential cook your battery by charging it too fast, hence the recommendation to simply use the car batter alone.
Leave the car off and just jump start your bike.  Ride the bike for 10 or 15 minutes and when you get home turn it off and try and start it on it's own.

My prediction is that it will be fine and the battery will be charged from your ride.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm going to try this later today and see if it works.

Comment: let us know how it works out.  interested in the outcome.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Why do you not want to have the car running while jumping the bike? Does it provide too much amperage that way? Educate this non-bike kinda person!

Comment: Awesome.  Wear helmet, don't speed and watch out for potholes and grazing animals.